# Listview refresh scrolling to wrong position

Tags: listview, scroll, nativescript

I am using `Listview` in my Nativescript application. In that I have items which consist overlay item which appears on clicking on more-icon on each card. But, whenever I click on item's more-icon, the view is updating to show overlay. So, I used `refresh` to show changes in view. But due to that `refresh`, view getting scrolled to different positions. Sometimes it is staying in actual position but sometimes it is scrolling.

Please let me know is am I doing anything wrong.

Thank you...

Comment: Include a Playground demo of your codebase https://play.nativescript.org/ or directly include the used code here

Answer (score 0):

Refresh method will render the whole list view again, so the scroll position won't be retained. That's absolutely expected behaviour.

If you want to show/hide any kind of overlay, bind it's visibility to a property in the data item, then toggle it's value upon click.

Comment: Hi @Manoj, I am doing the very same thing. But, the view is not getting updated. That is why I am using .refresh method.

Comment: Then the actual issue here is updating list item. Please share the Playground example where we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I used opacity to show/hide the overlay using `getViewById`. Now it is working fine. But, it is not correct solution.